# Media Style Notification action buttons not working with PendingIntent.getBroadcast()

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification.mediastyle

I am creating a music player with notification style by using `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()`.

I implemented my code to send a broadcast when the action buttons are clicked in my notification. But my code doesn't seems to work.

Here's my code as follows:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            // Set the Notification style
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                      // Attach our MediaSession token
                      .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                      // Show our playback controls in the compact notification view.
                      .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            // Set the Notification color
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            // Set the large and small icons
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            // Set Notification content information
            .setContentText("Artist Name")
            .setContentTitle("Album name")
            .setContentInfo("Title name")
            // Add playback actions
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "next", playbackAction(2));

((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Method `playBackAction()` is as follows:

```
private PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber){

        Intent playbackAction;

        switch(actionNumber){
        case 0:
            // Play
            playbackAction = new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK);
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);

            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 1:
            // Pause
            playbackAction = new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK);
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);

            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 2:
            // Next track
            playbackAction = new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK);
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);

            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 3:
            // Previous track
            playbackAction = new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK);
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);

            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My BroadcastReceiver is as follows:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadCastPlayback=new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method

            showToast("onReceive");
        }
    };
```

I registered the broadcast receiver in `onCreate` of the android `service`

```
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK);
registerReceiver(broadCastPlayback,filter);
```

The `showToast()` method inside `onReceive` is not called. I wonder whether the `broadcast` is not sent or it is not received.

Comment: check this answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820133/8391757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the filter is lacking the actions that are being sent in the pending intents.

For example: `.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3))` will send the action `ACTION_PREVIOUS`

but the boradcast receiver is filtering only on `BROADCAST_PLAYBACK`

To the filter you need to add (or replace BROADCAST_PLAYBACK with) the missing actions.

Following the example:

```
filter.addAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
```

In the same way add the other actions you have definied.